# where are the docker images stored in local disk

Tags: docker

In previous version of docker, the images are downloaded in .docker folder. 
In new release, I even could not find .docker folder under my home folder. Where are the images stored in local disk.

Now I am using 1.11.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker stores it's data in `/var/lib/docker` in 1.11.2.

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/.
total 36
drwx------ 5 root root  4096 May 11 13:37 aufs
drwx------ 4 root root  4096 Jun 15 07:53 containers
drwx------ 3 root root  4096 May 11 13:37 image
drwxr-x--- 3 root root  4096 May 11 13:37 network
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 Jun 14 09:38 tmp
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 May 11 13:37 trust
drwx------ 5 root root 12288 Jun 15 07:53 volumes
```

Comment: thanks, but I still cannot find the detail docker images, after searching the folder. For example, if I download and run a wordpress image, should I find and image file under this folder named wordpress?

Comment: Using the `docker images` you'll see the image there. If you run a `docker inspect $image_name` you'll see the image id, layer id's, etc. Using those id's, you can find the sha256 hash reference in `/var/lib/docker/image/aufs/imagedb/content/sha256` and `/var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/content/sha256` for images and layers respectively.

Comment: There's also the `/var/lib/docker/image/aufs/repositories.json` that contains the high level list of what's been built/downloaded with pointers to the metadata sha256 hashes.

Comment: Note `aufs` is just one storage option - you may also be using `overlay`, `devicemapper` or others.  The top-level directory changes accordingly, and the structure underneath it is completely different.